# JavaFX not support GPU hardware decoding?

Tags: java, javafx

Why does playing videos with JavaFX utilize CPU software decoding when my computer has a GPU? When I use VLC for playback, it uses GPU hardware decoding. Does JavaFX not support hardware decoding?

I am using JDK 17 and JavaFX 21.

Why does playing videos with JavaFX utilize CPU software decoding when my computer has a GPU? When I use VLC for playback, it uses GPU hardware decoding. Does JavaFX not support hardware decoding?

Comment: Please edit the question rather than asking the same question twice.

Comment: How do you know software decoding is used?  What is it? What gpu? What codec and container?  Do you have a [mcve](code and media file) that can tested to replicate? Edit the question to improve it.

Comment: If you want to use vlc for playback in Java, vlcj has javafx wrappers from caprice. It isn’t as convenient as the inbuilt javafx media api though.

Comment: Internally javafx media uses different native interfaces on different platforms.  On some desktops it uses gstreamer lite which can do  [hardware decoding with the appropriate plugins](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/playback/hardware-accelerated-video-decoding.html?gi-language=c).  Though I don’t know if javafx ships with any of those plugins.  Gstreamer in turn may rely on underlying issues media and hardware acceleration capabilities such as direct show on windows or libav on Linux.  The whole chain needs to be enabled for the accel feature and media codec.

Comment: With hardware acceleration according to the gstreamer guide, it works best if the frame data is never copied out of the gpu to a frame buffer in memory.  I don’t know if javafx can work that way or not for video frames.  I think it can for other texture content because it can handle hardware accelerated 2D and 3D rendering.

Comment: You can ask on the openjfx-dev mailing list if you want a JavaFX developer answer.

Comment: I might put all these comments in an answer later even though I haven’t really got an answer to this question and the answer may vary depending on OS, installed or packaged  libraries and codecs, encoding, container type and protocol used for media playback, etc. A comprehensive answer here is probably beyond reasonable scope.